# Why can I not delete localStorage data after refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a to do list with javascript, and to do items aren't being lost when page is refreshed. But after I refresh, the X button on my li items don't work, cannot delete it. Any reasons??? It used to be able to delete the items before I added localStorage to it :/

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
                <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="190"autofocus>
                <button id="enter" onclick="createListElement()">Add</button>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="items">
            <div class="listItems col-12">
                <ul class="col-12 offset-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);

    let arr = getTasks();

    arr.push(li.textContent);

    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(arr));
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (input.value.length > 0 && event.which === 13) {
        createListElement();
        input.value = '';
    }
}

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

function getTasks() {
    let tasks;
    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
        tasks = [];
    } else {
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }
    return tasks;
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let arr = getTasks();
    let foo = '';
    arr.forEach(item => {
        foo += `<li>${item}<button>X</button></li>`;
    });

    ul.innerHTML = foo;

    var li = document.createElement("li"); 
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    input.value = "";
    var dBtn = document.createElement("button");
    dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    li.appendChild(dBtn);
    dBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);

    function deleteListItem(){
        li.classList.add("delete");
    }
});

function addListAfterClick(){
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing that would act on clicking the "X" button.

Comment: All your `deleteListItem()` function does is add a class to the element ... it doesn't attempt to remove anything from storage

Comment: How are you determining that the click is not occurring? At this point what are you expecting the click to do exactly?

Comment: @charlietfl I am expecting the X button to delete the li

Comment: Well there is no functionality written in the code shown that would do that. The click calls `deleteListItem()` which only changes a class. You need some delete logic written

Comment: Even if `deleteListIem()` would actually delete anything, the list items from `localStorage` have no `click` event handler at all.

Comment: How would I make the delete logic? I having a brain fart

Comment: sorry this is my first time using local storage

Comment: Two things... you need the current array of data from which you would remove the item clicked and set updated array  back in storage and you need to remove that element from page also

Comment: The array modification will take some research into how to look for a specific element in an array and how to remove it from that array.

Comment: I don't understand and how do I do that?

Comment: Each aspect will require you to do some basic research

Comment: I am js noob...

Comment: That's fine...just means you will need to do more research into dealing with arrays. Understand that SO isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Every developer has had to do such research and it is a huge part of learning to write code. Even seasoned developers have to do lots of research...it's all part of the game